# Creating an horizontal flip book using bookBlock jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, bookblock

As a newbie in jQuery I'm trying to create an horizontal flip book using the bookBlock jQuery plugin and also this tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/comment-page-3/#comments

I've choose this one because it already have a table of content, which I realy need.

So at one point I'm supposed to add the next options in the bookBlock configuration :

```
orientation : 'horizontal',
direction: 'rtl',
```

That will allow me to configure the bookBlock as I want. But when I write this in this place, in the page.js file, it's not working, the direction and the oriention doesn't change:

```
bb = $( '#bb-bookblock' ).bookblock( {
        orientation : 'horizontal',
        direction: 'rtl',
        speed : 800,
        perspective : 2000,
        shadowSides : 0.8,
        shadowFlip  : 0.4,
        onEndFlip : function(old, page, isLimit) {

            current = page;
            // update TOC current
            updateTOC();
            // updateNavigation
            updateNavigation( isLimit );
            // initialize jScrollPane on the content div for the new item
            setJSP( 'init' );
            // destroy jScrollPane on the content div for the old item
            setJSP( 'destroy', old );

        }
    } ),
```

I also tried to add this to the default configuration in the jquery.bookblock.js file, here :

```
$.BookBlock.defaults = { //ALL THE OPTIONS }
```

Is there someone here who can tell where to modify the options to get the result I'm expected, please ?

Answer (score 0):

It took my a while to understand this too.

In the tutorial they are using v1 of the plugin - but the RTL option added only at V2.
You can try use [that](https://github.com/layalk/BookBlock/tree/rtl) version, which based on V1.